# HTML Video not appearing on mobile

Tags: html, video

My video that works perfectly fine on desktop (even with a mobile viewport with) won't even show up on mobile. I've seen tons of questions like these about autoplay, but for me the issue is the video not even showing up.

Trying to make this work for iOS especially.

```
<div class="HmySlides">
            <video src="./DRAW/Plakat1.mp4" alt="HmySlides" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline>
        </div>
```

Also tried the code like this:

```
<div class="HmySlides">
            <video alt="HmySlides" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline>
                <source src="./DRAW/Plakat1.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your first example is thoroughly invalid HTML. Your second example also has errors but might not be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your video works on mobile devices, especially iOS, you can follow these recommendations:

1. Use the **controls** attribute: Adding the controls attribute to your
    tag will display the video controls, which can be useful for
   mobile users to manually start the video playback.

```html
<div class="HmySlides">
    <video controls autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline>
        <source src="./DRAW/Plakat1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

2. Provide a fallback format: Including a fallback format for your
   video, such as MP4 (H.264), is a good practice to ensure
   compatibility across different browsers and devices.
3. Make sure the video file path is correct: Double-check that the
   the video file path is accurate and that the file exists at the
   specified location.
4. Ensure your server supports video MIME types: Sometimes, videos may
   not load on mobile devices if the server is not configured to serve
   the correct MIME type for videos. Make sure your server is set up to
   serve video files with the appropriate MIME types.
5. Check for JavaScript or CSS conflicts: If you have JavaScript or CSS
   that might be conflicting with the video display, it could lead to
   issues. Make sure there are no errors or conflicts in your web
   page's code.
6. Update iOS: Occasionally, issues with video playback on iOS devices
   maybe resolved by updating the device's operating system.

> By following these recommendations, you can increase the chances of
> your video working on mobile devices, including iOS. If the issue
> persists, it may be related to the specific configuration or
> constraints of your website or hosting environment, so further
> troubleshooting may be necessary.